# Connect is failing every time (also getting Illegal Instruction: 4)

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

```
int connect_to_host(char* server_ip, char* server_port)
{
    printf("%s\n", "in connect to host");
    printf("server_ip in connect_to_host: %s\n", server_ip);
    printf("server_port in connect_to_host: %s\n", server_port);
    struct sockaddr_in remote_server_addr;
    int fdsocket, port;
    uint16_t port = atoi(server_port);
    socklen_t len = sizeof(remote_server_addr);
    fdsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(fdsocket < 0) {
        printf("%s\n", "socket error");
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&remote_server_addr, 0, sizeof(remote_server_addr));

    remote_server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    remote_server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_ip);
    //inet_pton(AF_INET, server_ip, &remote_server_addr.sin_addr);
    remote_server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    printf("remote server port after htons: %d\n", remote_server_addr.sin_port);

    if(connect(fdsocket, (struct sockaddr*)&remote_server_addr, &len) < 0) {
        printf("%s\n", "connect error");
        return -1;
    }

    return fdsocket;
}
```

The output of this block:

```
in connect to host 
server_ip in connect_to_host: 192.168.1.179 
server_port in connect_to_host: 49200 
remote server port after htons: 12480 
connect error 
[LOGIN:ERROR] 
[LOGIN:END] 
Illegal instruction: 4
```

The server is initialized with port 49200 and it's IP is the same as that of the client (testing on local machine) - 192.168.1.179.

I can't understand why the connect is failing. Cause I have carried out connect() in the same way in a different function, just that the connection is UDP in that case and it works fine. Is it because I am trying to connect to the same IP?

I am pretty new to this. Let me know if you need more parts of the code.

Comment: do perror instead of printf - you will get an explanation of the error

Comment: Okay. Thanks for that! 
I am getting file name too long error.
What does that mean?

Comment: @Myst `htons()`is correct there. See the *man* page. Do you have a reason for thinking otherwise?

Comment: @EJP - I wasn't sure, since the address struct is used by the local API and I wasn't sure if it's translated before being sent over the wire... okay, I found it in the `man` page, sorry about that.

Comment: Take the compiler's warnings serious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(connect(fdsocket, (struct sockaddr*)&remote_server_addr, &len) < 0) {
    printf("%s\n", "connect error");
    return -1;
}
```

The problem is here. The third argument to `connect()` is an `addrlen_t`, not a pointer. It should be:

```
if(connect(fdsocket, (struct sockaddr*)&remote_server_addr, len) < 0) {
    perror("connect error");
    return -1;
}
```

Printing your own error message *instead* of the one that `errno` or `perror()` or `strerror()` gives you is a complete waste of time. Don't do that. Every time *any* system call fails you must print or log or return the actual error.

Obviosuly the 'illegal instruction' problem cannot be coming from this code, as you have printed further messages after it exited.

Comment: Okay. That worked, sort of. Now I am getting 'Connection refused.' Seems the server never executes the listening part and it's beyond me as to why. :(

Comment: I suggest you *debug* it, starting with the suggestion in my 2nd-last paragraph.

Comment: Yep. Doing that. Thanks a lot! 
Although, there's this thing with gdb and Mac, and I am not sure if there are fixes for macOS 10.13, but I don't have enough time left for this assignment to try and fix that. So trying to debug with a print statement after each line.

Oh. And this assignment, a multi-client chat app is the first time I am coding in C. :P

Comment: NB The compiler must have give you a warning about the problem above. Don't just ignore them.